# Hibernate and Oracle overstate sequence incrementing

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I use Hibernate 4 and Oracle 11g. Having such a code for mapping an object to the DB:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPLICATION", schema = "PRODUCTION")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Application")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Application {

    @Id
    @ComparatorIgnore
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PRODUCTION.SEQUENCE_NEW")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PRODUCTION.SEQUENCE_NEW", schema = "PRODUCTION", sequenceName = "PRODUCTION.SEQUENCE_NEW", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @XmlTransient
    @Getter @Setter private Long id;
```

I get such a sequence of id (after some time), and it continues to produce further values with weird gaps:

```
956493
955431
956174
955995
950593
950720
952045
950998
951905
950860
949323
950058
949084
948981
948884
948786
950182
950345
949952
950469
```

I assumed to get more steady and flat growth. Considering that I have multithread application I wonder how to fix this unexpected behavior. 
This is how the sequence is defined:

```
CREATED         27.02.17
LAST_DDL_TIME   27.02.17
SEQUENCE_OWNER  PRODUCTION
SEQUENCE_NAME   SEQUENCE_NEW
MIN_VALUE       1
MAX_VALUE       9999999999999999999999999999
INCREMENT_BY    1
CYCLE_FLAG      N
ORDER_FLAG      N
CACHE_SIZE      20
LAST_NUMBER     957101
PARTITION_COUNT 
SESSION_FLAG    N
KEEP_VALUE      N
```

What did I miss? 
Many thanks in advance. Any answer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gaps can be explained in a number of ways.

First, `CACHE_SIZE 20` indicates that Oracle can use an optimization where it reserves 20 id's so it doesn't have to check the sequence for every insert.  If they're not all used, this may leave gaps.  When accessing the database over multiple connection, each connection could reserve 20 id's if it has to change the tables involved.

Second, transactions that are rolled back can also leave gaps depending on your database.  This is pretty normal.

There is no reason to fix this, Oracle guarantees there are no duplicates.  It doesn't guarantee that the sequence is without gaps or exactly in order.

Comment: According to the @john16384 's answer and this document [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm#sthref2219), "The database does not wait for a transaction that has incremented a sequence to complete before that sequence can be incremented again". Now it's pretty clear, thank you for your consideration.

Comment: why the `max_value` is `9999999999999999999999999999`?